# Detect overflow and carry when working with 16b values

Tags: c, addition, carryflag

I'm working with signed 16 bit wide variables.
When adding, subtracting etc, can i detect the carry and overflow the following way:

I store the result in a 32bit wide variable, and then check the 17th bit (bits from 0-16 represent the value, and if there's carry or overflow the 17h bit should be 1 - overflow)?
If it's one then it's an overflow/carry, if it's zero - it isn't.
Can carry happen without overflow, or vice versa, when working with 16b values?

I searched StackOverflow, but i was unable to find a clear answer to my question.

Comment: "Carry" is a concept from unsigned arithmetic, "overflow" is a concept from signed arithmetic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265896/arithmetic-overflow-vs-arithmetic-carry.

Comment: Did you even try to convert your method into code?

Comment: I have an assignment, which requiries of me to work with signed values, and i need to set both carry and overflow flags :).

Can i detect overflow in signed values, by storing the result in a 32b values (and operands are 16b, and then check if the result is greater than  32767 and less than 32768

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth Disagree that the duplicate referenced strongly applies here.  In this case, the overflow post is about 16-bit integers and C, though `long` supports 32-bit or wider integers.  In the dupe, the question is about `int` addition.  C does not guarantee the `long`, `long long`, etc. are wider than `int` and so good portable answers then need to do the various tests on `INT_MAX`, etc.  Here all one needs to do is `int16_t a,b; long sum = (long) a + b; if (sum > 32767) || (sum < -32768) Ovrflow()`.  A complete answer would discus `int32_t vs. long` and `int16_t vs. short`.

Comment: @chux: The mechanisms given in the answers there are largely equivalent to what you're suggesting, though.

Answer (score 0):

upd:
One can use approach, when operands are testing against the limits (declared in the limits.h) when doing the operation. E.g. look at this "safe" addition function:

```
int safe_add(int x, int y)
{
    if(y < 0)
       return save_sub(x, -y);
    if(x > (INT_MAX - y)) 
    {
        printf("overflow\n");
        return INT_MAX;
    }
    return x + y;
}

int save_sub(int x, int y)
{
    if(y < 0)
        return save_add(x, -y);
    if(x > (INT_MIN + y)) 
    {
        printf("underflow\n");
        return INT_MIN;
    }
    return x - y;
}
```

Note: these methods have at least one bug: they may fail if invoked on the largest negative integer, INT_MIN.

Comment: I don't want to test if it's safe. I just want to execute it, and then indicate if overflow happened.

Comment: @Matt McNabb, you're right, i forget to mention this case. Added this to case to code.

Comment: @Nicholas In C, signed integer math, overflow is undefined behavior.  That means that should such overflow occur, the rest of the code is pointless.  One cannot test _after_ overflow.  Code needs to occur such that overflow (at that integer width) never occurs.  Going to wider integers or doing tests like this post are the 2 main options.